# Как получить выделенный текст с div

Tags: jquery

Есть такая HTML структура, как при помощи JS получить фрагмент выделенного текста в DIV с классом divtext?

Если использовать window.getSelection() то поиск получается ао всей странице а нужно только в div с классом divtext.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#go", function () {

    alert("You selected: "+window.getSelection()); //Оно ищет на всей странице а нужно только в div
    return false;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="go">Найти виделеный текст</button>
<div class="divtext">

  <div>Текст - 1</div>
  <div>Текст - 2</div>
  <div>Текст - 3</div>
  <div>Текст - 4</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on("click", "#go", function () {
  let selectedText = window.getSelection();
  if (selectedText != '') {
    let parentNodeClass = getSelectionParentElement().parentNode.className;
    if( parentNodeClass != "divtext") { 
      return;
    }
    alert("You selected: " + selectedText + ", id = " + getSelectionParentElement().id );
  }
});

function getSelectionParentElement() {
    var parentEl = null, sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            parentEl = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
            if (parentEl.nodeType != 1) {
                parentEl = parentEl.parentNode;
            }
        }
    } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        parentEl = sel.createRange().parentElement();
    }
    return parentEl;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="go">Найти виделеный текст</button>
<div class="divtext">

  <div id="1">Текст - 1</div>
  <div id="2">Текст - 2</div>
  <div id="3">Текст - 3</div>
  <div id="4">Текст - 4</div>

</div>

<div class="divtext2">

  <div>test - 1</div>
  <div>test - 2</div>
  <div>test - 3</div>
  <div>test - 4</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Очень помогли.

Comment: А можно как то получить id того div  в котором было выделение? Я был бы Вам очень признателен если подскажете как это сделать или навидете пример.

Comment: @Tokwiro `let parentNodeClass = getSelectionParentElement().parentNode.className;` заменить на `let parentNodeId = getSelectionParentElement().parentNode.id;` (ну и дальше в if сменить имя переменной т.к. оно поменялось в моём примере)

Comment: parentNode.className пусть будет, видь текст я беру именно с общего div с классом divtext просто в div может бить еще id который я хочу узнать и использовать дальше.  <div id="22">Текст - 1</div> вот этот id я хочу узнать. Возможно это?

Comment: Т.е. нужен именно id эл-та в котором выбран текст?

Comment: да именно это нужно

Comment: Отредактировал ответ. добавил вывод id в alert

Comment: Еще раз благодарю Вас, Вы мне очень помогли. Я могу Вас как то отблагодарить?

Comment: Отблагодарили ответом уже)

Comment: Не работает в хроме проверяю так let selectedText = window.getSelection();
alert(selectedText); результат ноль, но в фаерфокс работает. В чем причина?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95230/discussion-between-indevx-and-tokwiro).